# Difference between commands.ts and index.d.ts

Tags: typescript, cypress-custom-commands

When researching custom commands for TypeScript, I see some articles talking about defining these in commands.ts and others recommending creating custom commands in index.d.ts. What is the difference between these two files?

I haven't tried this specifically as I ma hitting multiple, cascading issues. I started by trying to create a custom command in commands.ts only to hit the error:

`Argument of type "login" is not assignable to parameter of type "keyOf Chainable<any>".`

Researching this, it describes having to declare custom commands but that is where I find some articles using commands.ts and others using index.d.ts.